# Custom main menu with rotating android

Tags: android, menu, surfaceview

I would like to make an application with a custom main menu. However, I want to have a different menu, with a circle and items around it. The user can select each item rotating the device.

[image]

Should I use a Surface View to draw them and make the animation or there is an easier way for that ?

Comment: u think about something!! so do it, then if u couldn't give an answer, show us your source.

Comment: why do it if there is someone can tell me if i there is easier way to do it ? i don't want to waste my time if there is another easier way!

Comment: read about stackoverflow. stackoverflow is a place for ask about YOUR problems.it means you must write a code, then get a problem, then ask here. you just want an answer. so search in internet and do COPY/PASTE , so easy way.

Answer (score 1):

- Yes, you should draw the background and the text using a surface view.
- You will need to rotate the background and the text when the device rotates.
- This is a fairly simple way to implement it. The rotation is probably the only hard part. Just make a small version to test the code of the main functionality and then build it step by step.